# Trying to create and test a comparable arraylist class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Here's the code I have. I'm trying to test out my bubbleSort Method..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyArrayList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends ArrayList<Comparable<T>> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private MyArrayList<T> myList; // class list

public MyArrayList(ArrayList<Comparable<T>> asList) {
    for (Comparable<T> e: asList) {
        myList.add(e);
    }
}

public void bubbleSort() {
    boolean swapped = true;

    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (this.get(i).compareTo((T) this.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                swapped = true;
                Comparable<T> temp = this.get(i);
                this.set(i, this.get(i + 1));
                this.set(i + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my test class, I am having trouble creating lists to test my bubbleSort method. I want to try to create an Integer list (from an array), a String list, and a few others, but I keep getting various errors.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;


public class MyArrayListTest<T> {

public void setUp() {
    Integer[] testIntArray = new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3};
    MyArrayList<Integer> myList = new MyArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(testIntArray));
}
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work, and how I would go about creating a MyArrayList?

Comment: Why does a MyArrayList instance needs another MyArrayList instance to work? Does the get() method of ArrayList go find elements in `myList`?

Comment: The idea was to create a MyArrayList object and then just call .bubbleSort on it. I created the constructor, because I couldn't find a way around not using one.

Comment: Having a constructor is not the problem I'm trying to show you. Having a field myList is what doesn't make sense. You're doing inheritance here, not composition.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I've gotten rid of both myList and the constructor, but still cannot create an instance with an integer array like this: MyArrayList<Integer> myList = new MyArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0, 1, 2}));

Comment: How do you intend to construct an instance of MyArrayList with a List as argument if you don't provide a constructor taking a List as argument? Extending ArrayList is a bad, bad idea. Especially if you don't understand constructors yet, and even less generics.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet. Start by making `bubbleSort` a `static` method that sorts an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @JBNizet what would be the best way to implement a bubble sort that takes in any comparable?

Comment: What is the signature of Collections.sort()? Shouldn't the signature of bubbleSort() be similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your constructor from:

```
public MyArrayList(ArrayList<Comparable<T>> asList)
```

to:

```
public MyArrayList(List<T> asList)
```

`Arrays.asList` doesn't return a `java.util.ArrayList`, which is why `new MyArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(testIntArray))` doesn't compile. `Arrays.asList` returns an instance of a nested class defined inside the `Arrays` class, which is also called `ArrayList`, but more importantly, the return type of `Arrays.asList(T... a)` is `List<T>`.

Comment: I am sure adding this part will not hurt **The java.util.Arrays.asList(T... a) returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs,**

Comment: Correct, but in fact, the concrete class of the returned list doesn't matter. All the compiler cares about is the *declared* return-type of asList(): List.

Comment: I made the change, but still get the error. Eclipse is telling me "The constructor MyArrayList<Integer>(List<Integer>) is 
 undefined".

Comment: @glcohen The constructor requires a `List<Comparable>`. A `List<Integer>` is not a `List<Comparable>`.

Comment: @JBNizet but if the constructor expects a `java.util.ArrayList<Comparable<T>>` argument, it wouldn't accept a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList<Comparable<T>>`

Comment: If the constructor took a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList<Comparable<T>>`, it wouldn't accept `Arrays.asList()` as argument either, because the declared returned type of `Arrays.asList()` is not `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. It's `java.util.List`. The compiler doesn't care about the concrete type returned by the method. It cares about the declared type.

Comment: @glcohen Edit: The constructor should accept a `List<T>` not `ArrayList<Comparable<T>`.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, I see what you are saying. True

Answer (score 3):

Several problems here.

First, once you declared the base type of the list to be comparable, you shouldn't be using `Comparable<T>` anymore. This is actually what breaks your constructor. It expects a list of `Comparable` of something, and gets a list of `Integer`. Although an `Integer` is a `Comparable`, a `List<Integer>` is **not** a `List<Comparator>`. These are two different types.

---

Second, as you were told, the method `Arrays.asList()` returns a `List` and that's not assignment-compatible to `ArrayList` without type casting (and will fail on type casting, because it's not a `java.util.ArrayList`).

So the declaration of your constructor should actually be

```
public MyArrayList(List<T> asList)
```

And your loop variable `e` should also be declared as `T`. The basic fact is that Java already knows that `T` extends `Comparable` so it knows it has a `compareTo()` method.

---

But you also have a logical error which you have not ran into so far because of the constructor declaration. You actually have two collections in a `MyArrayList`. One is the *field* `myList`, and the other is `this`. Since you are extending an `ArrayList`, `this` *is an* `ArrayList`.

In your constructor, you add data to `myList`. But in your sort method, you are comparing and swapping the data in `this`! This means that it will probably attempt to sort an empty list, as you didn't fill it up in the constructor (unless you call its `add` method from your main).

In fact, adding information to `myList` will probably throw a `NullPointerException` as you did not initialize `myList` and you have no way of doing so as it is a `MyArrayList`, and has only the List-based constructor, which, if you will use, will send you on an infinite loop and end up with a Stack Overflow.

---

The list itself should probably extend `ArrayList<T>` rather than `ArrayList<Comparable<T>>`. Again, `T` is already known to extend `Comparable`. And then you could declare the `temp` variable `T` rather than `Comparable<T>`. It should also be unnecessary to cast the argument to `T` as it will already be `T`, being the base type of `this`.